# Windows Server 2012 Configuring - A subnetting scheme for a new office

Tags: networking

I am studying for Windows Server 2012 (exam 20410D) and came across this problem that was given no answers.  I'm not sure how to begin with it, though I have gone over subnetting multiple times in the last year. Any help would be appreciated!

> You are designing an appropriate network
>   configuration for a new campus. You have been
>   allocated the 10.34.0.0/16 network that you can
>   subnet as required, given these requirements:
>   
> • There are four buildings on the new campus,
>   and each should have its own subnet to allow
>   for routing between the buildings.
>   
> • Each building will have up to 700 users.
>   
> • Each building will have network printers that will require IP addresses.
>   
> • The typical ratio of users to printers is 50 to 1.
>   
> • You need to allocate a subnet for the server data center that will hold up to 100 servers.

Each building will have up to 700 users and 14 printers, all of which will require static IP addresses.  Plus a subnet for the data center.  Should only have a max of 500 ips per subnet (best practices), so 2 subnets per building plus one for data center... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First step is to figure out how many subnets you will need.

"You are designing an appropriate network configuration for a new campus. You have been allocated the 10.34.0.0/16 network that you can subnet as required, given these requirements:

• There are four buildings on the new campus, and each should have its own subnet to allow for routing between the buildings.
• Each building will have up to 700 users.
• Each building will have network printers that will require IP addresses.
• The typical ratio of users to printers is 50 to 1.
• You need to allocate a subnet for the server data center that will hold up to 100 servers."

2. Use Variable Length Subnet Mask (VLSM) to break up your subnets beginning with the biggest subnet and work down. Otherwise you will have overlapping address space. From the question above looks like you will need 6 subnets as shown below.

Subnet Building #1 = 700 users
Subnet Building #2 = 700 users
Subnet Building #3 = 700 users
Subnet Building #4 = 700 users
Subnet Data Center #5 = 100
Subnet Printer Server #6 = 56 (14 Printers for each building)

3. Subnet should as shown below:

Building #1 = 10.34.0.0 /22
Building #2 = 10.34.4.0 /22
Building #3 = 10.34.8.0 /22
Building #4 = 10.34.12.0 /22
Data Center #5 = 10.34.16.0/25
Print Server #6 = 10.34.16.128/26

Comment: Thanks for the helping me to think through the problem. I was going to share the table I came up with, but the lack of formatting options for replies makes it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First note that the question uses 'subnet' for two slightly different things: prefixes used for *routing*, as well as prefixes assigned directly to an *interface*. Things like "maximum number of users" only apply to the latter.

So if you have a /16 and five buildings, one way to start is to first assign one *large* subnetwork (e.g. a /19 or /20) to be routed to each building, then divide *that* up into as many tiny subnets as you want. For example – 10.34.0.0/19 is routed to building 1, then 10.34.32.0/19 is routed to building 2, and so on.

Once you have that, you can start assigning smaller subnets within each building – e.g. a /24 or /25 for printers, another /24 or /25 for PCs in Dept. #1, another for PCs in Dept. #2, maybe a /22 for Wi-Fi clients, and so on.

This way you can have relatively small broadcast domains (and the ability to firewall offices from each other) while still having a small core routing table.

*(Disclaimer: None of the above is expert advice; I'm just making things up as I go.)*

Comment: Hey thanks!  I think what gets me most of the time is the arbitrary nature of networking - like when deciding on what ip to assign a new domain, for example.  At home I just chose 192.168.0 for my network and randomly chose 101 for the server ip.  Your logic will help me get going on this problem.  I expected it to have a specific answer, but it looks like it could have many many answers.